# Using <tr> as read more function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it's possible, in vanilla javascript, if I can have each of my table rows act as a "Read more" button. Essentially, if the text in each table row is longer than a set number of words or characters, you would click the row and It would expand to see the full length text. I don't know if I've formatted them correctly so far. Anything helps, thanks!

**Edit:** I've tried setting up an :onclick event for my table rows but it didn't work since my row heights are dependant on the content inside. Don't know a way around this in CSS so assuming something in vanilla JS can be done.

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@font-face { font-family: Raleway; src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');}

/*Styling*/
* {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


a {
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {margin: 0px;}

p {margin: 0px;}

ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


input {
  display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}

button {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
    border: none !important;
}


/*Table CSS*/

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px;
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 1170px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
table * {
  position: relative;
}
table td, table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #36304a;
}
table tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
}
table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
table td, table th {
  text-align: left;
}
table td.l, table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}
table td.c, table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}
table td.r, table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}


.table100-head th{
  font-family: Raleway;
  background-color:#3A81B4;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #2f2e2e;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
  background-color:#fcfcfc;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight:500;
}

.column1 {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top:10px;
   padding-bottom:10px;
}

.column2 {
  width: 1px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-table100">
            <div class="wrap-table100">
                <div class="table100">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table100-head">
                                <th class="column1">Limitations</th>
                                <th class="column2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                                    <td class="column2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what've you tried so far?

Comment: Just set up a `click` event handler on the row that changes its height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How this JavaScript works:

The script counts letters ... I have currently set it to count 30 letters `var max = 30;` In order not to cut words, check the words that can be collected in this number of letters. The rest of the text is closed in a SPAN element with class "read_more". On each item with class "column1" is placed a listener for a click. When clicked, it adds or removes the "read_more" class of the SPAN element.

At the end of your css I added style ".read_more"

```js
// Number of letters
var max = 30;
// If you don't want "..." after the short text, change text here or add "false"
var dots = '...';

var tableDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.table100 .column1');
for (var i = 1; i < tableDiv.length; i++) {

    var w = tableDiv[i].innerText.split(' ');
    var sum = 0;
    var comp = 0;
    var l = 0;
    for (let ii = 0; ii < w.length; ii++) {
        sum = w[ii].length + sum;
        if (sum > max) { break; } else { comp = sum; l = ii + 1; }
    }

    if (sum > max) {
        w.splice(l, 0, '<span class="read_more">');
        tableDiv[i].innerHTML = w.join(' ');

        if (dots) {
            tableDiv[i].innerHTML += '<span>' + dots + '</span>';
        }

        tableDiv[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            closeOpen(this);
        });
    }

}

function closeOpen(x) {
    x.children[0].classList.toggle("read_more");
    if (dots) {
        x.children[1].classList.toggle("read_more");
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: Raleway;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
}

/*Styling*/
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


a {
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
}

ul,
li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


input {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
}

textarea {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

button {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
    border: none !important;
}


/*Table CSS*/

.limiter {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-table100 {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 33px 30px;
}

.wrap-table100 {
    width: 1170px;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 1;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

table * {
    position: relative;
}

table td,
table th {
    padding-left: 8px;
}

table thead tr {
    height: 60px;
    background: #36304a;
}

table tbody tr {
    height: 50px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
    border: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
    text-align: left;
}

table td.l,
table th.l {
    text-align: right;
}

table td.c,
table th.c {
    text-align: center;
}

table td.r,
table th.r {
    text-align: center;
}


.table100-head th {
    font-family: Raleway;
    background-color: #3A81B4;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #2f2e2e;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: unset;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.column1 {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.column2 {
    width: 1px;
}

.read_more {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table100">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table100-head">
                            <th class="column1">Limitations</th>
                            <th class="column2"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                                labore et dolore.</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                                aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                eiusmod tempor incididunt.</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                                fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
                                qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                            <td class="column2"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good demonstration of how the problem could be approached. It should be noted that additional work will need to be done in order to make it accessible.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thank you for explaining the code as well!